# How to fix dataTables pagination at a minimum height from top?

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables

Consider a Datatable:

```
var x = $('#tab').dataTable({
    "aaData": sourc,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bRedraw": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[1,10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [1,10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
    "aoColumns": [
        {"mData": "Title1"},
        {"mData": "Title2"},
        {"mData": "Language"}
    ]
});
```

Now if the length of my table is 10 ROWS the pagination is at bottom and keeps going down as I increase the size.

What can be done so that if the height is less than 10 ROWS the pagination still remains at the constant height/distance of 10 ROWS from top regardless of number of rows?

It should keeps going down if I increase - but effectively, giving the table a MIN height.Scroll is not needed.

I've tried using sDom and also 
setting min-height from CSS and
using jQuery to try and take it out of dataTables wrapper.

Is there a way to do this or move it out of wrapper to fix min height?